# What is this metal bar going into the back of an old metal receptacle?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

What this metal bar thing that attaches to the inside back of this old receptacle? It comes out of the side of the box then goes down the wall to where I cannot see. It looks like copper but a magnet will stick to it, so I guess it's steel.

[image: Copper bar in metal receptacle]

[image: Copper bar in receptacle 3]
[image: copper bar in receptacle 2]

The bar is quite thick, so at first I thought it was some sort of brace, but it's also long, irregularly shaped, and doesn't immediately connect to anything else. The building is from the early 60's and I'm not sure what conventions they had then.

I'm trying to replace this 2 gang with a 3, but the original metal box is going to be tricky to remove. It is similar to the example below, in that there's a side bracket sticking out at the top and bottom that holds it to the stud with nails. So I expect my only solution is to saw it out.

Example (not same model):
[image: Example metal receptacle 2 gang new work]

Can I just cut this copper bar thing out? Is it structural, or some sort of grounding thing?

**Update:** I painstakingly cut the old receptacle brackets and the metal bar then removed it all. The part of the bar that remained in the wall was quite loose, so I would not consider it used for bracing.

[image: old receptacle removed from wall]
[image: old receptacle back view]

[image: metal bar removed after being cut]

Extra photos for context:

[image: Receptacle Unopened]
[image: Receptacle zoomed out]

Comment: It can not be other then grounding

Comment: @Ruskes - Why might it be so thick? It's easily 10 times thicker than a 12 guage wire.

Comment: Can you get a small magnet on it and see if it's magnetic? It could be copper plated steel. Any evidence that the home was formerly owned by a ham radio operator?

Comment: @MTA Yep a magnet sticks to it! No evidence of a HAM radio past life though. This is a bathroom, which I would guess has always been a bathroom.

Comment: It's not some kind of mounting bracket for the box, is it?

Comment: @Huesmann That's what I had asked.

Comment: If there are no screws or nails holding the box then @Huesmann is probably correct.  It's some kind of old school Madison Bar.  (Not a beer joint in Wisconsin).

Comment: @SteveWellens There _are_ nails holding the box. It would seem I need to compose my question better, as things aren't clear to readers.

Comment: @Bort looks like you cut the bar...gotta pic of the other piece?

Comment: @Huesmann The other piece is shown in the 3rd photo (2nd photo on 2nd line). I pulled on it but it didn't come out, so I just left it there. But it was also free to wiggle several inches, so it certainly wasn't functioning as a good bracket.

Comment: Did you leave it in the wall?

Comment: @Huesmann "I pulled on it but it didn't come out, so I just left it there."

Comment: Was the metal box fastened to the wall in any other way?

Comment: @Huesmann It was nailed to the wall as stated in the question.

Comment: It was probably (before being broken) to attach the box to a stud but not directly adjacent to the stud.

Comment: I'd be most interested in how this would have been used as grounding.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely a mounting bracket, although it appears it was used incorrectly.

Comment: It might be helpful if you could indicate _how_ it should have been used, for future reference...

Comment: It appears to have been cut, because those brackets would usually span a bay, or to stabilize one side of it before the metal boxes had vertical metal brackets attached to them.  see  https://bityl.co/HYhN